# Toggle div within a div using an image

Tags: jquery

I have the following code currently:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#toggleinput').click(function () {
            $('[id^=POPUP]').toggle()
        });
        $(".img-swap").on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
                this.src = this.src.replace("_showall", "_hideall");
            } else {
                this.src = this.src.replace("_hideall", "_showall")
            }
            $(this).toggleClass("on");
        });
    });
});
```

I have a div called `div id="input"` and within that there are an assortment (from 3-50+) other divs that called `div id="POPUP{Some number}"`.

So I have this:

```
<div id="input">
    <div id="POPUP438748234793"></div>
    <div id="POPUP437857482782"></div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to only toggle those POPUP divs that are within the "input" div. There will be another div called "Response" that will also have POPUP divs. So I want to use this code in two places with a different parent div. Right now, the code above toggles *ALL* the POPUP divs and not just the ones under input. How do I do that?

I'm new to JQuery, but I think it's really great thus far!

**EDIT**
Oddly enough, none of these seem to be working. Perhaps I'm missing something or I haven't given you everything to help with this issue (probably the latter). Below is part of the html from the output I produce (I'm doing this in a separate application, so some of the code you see you may be wondering why it's even there, but because of the setup, I can't really change it (and don't want to take the hours it would take to do mass modifications each time a change is made)).

```
<div id="input">
    <div>
<ul style="list-style: disc;">
    <li class="Input1-Bullet"><p class="Input-Bullet"><a class="dropspot" href="javascript:TextPopup(this)" id="a3">merchantId</a></p>
    <div class="droptext" id="POPUP581417197" style="display: none;">
        <p class="Body1-Text">Logical Definition: This is the general definition of what the input type is in common terms.</p>
        <p class="Body1-Text">Technical Definition: This is the technical        definition of what the input type is; for example, it is the data stored in the X column 
     of the Y table.</p>
        <p class="Body1-Text">Required: Y/N</p>
        <p class="Body1-Text">Input Information: varchar 32, etc.</p>
    </div></li>
</ul>
```

That extra `<div>` tag is added by the application when it creates the output html file. I can't really stop it, and editing it out would take more time and be problematic in the long run. Essentially, the line with `merchantId` would be visible. It can be clicked to display the information in the div (POPUP) below. I want to display all these POPUP divs with a single button at the top so long as they are within the `input` div.

**EDIT 2**
My mistake. I found the error in that I didn't have my image called `toggleinput`. I have it working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `children` method. For example, instead of doing `$('[id^=POPUP]').toggle()`, you could do `$("#input").children('div').toggle();`, assuming those are the only divs inside of `input`.

If there's more than just the popup divs, you could do `$("#input").children('div[id^=POPUP]').toggle();`, but the first is a little cleaner if you don't need the disambiguation.

You can see other examples at http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 0):

This will select ALL elements within `#input` that have id of `POPUP`. Using `.children()` will only go down one level in the DOM. http://api.jquery.com/find/

```
$('#input').find('[id^=POPUP]').toggle()
```

If you know that you have to select all the `div` elements in `#input` then replace `[id^=POPUP]` with `div` and it will work.

Also you shouldn't need the `$(function (){ ... });` that wraps the code. The `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to do a bit of swatting up about selectors.  You can nest selectors so you could do this...

```
$("div#input div")
```

and that will select all the divs within the div with id of input.

Alternatively, you could use...

```
$("div#input > div")
```

which will only select the immediate child divs of the input div (in case any of the popup divs have divs within them).

Answer (score 0):

replace $('[id^=POPUP]').toggle() with $('div#input > div[id^=POPUP]').toggle()

jsfiddle.net/zrpVm/